# Laravel Eloquent 'updating' event flaky - not always respected

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my model I have the following code:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::updating(function (self $run) {
        if ($run->isDirty('status')) {
            if ($run->status !== 'active') {
                $run->next_step_id = null;
            }
        }
    });
}

....

public function markAs($status)
{
    return tap($this)->update([
        'status' => $status,
        'finished_at' => now(),
    ]);
}
```

`markAs` is the only method that updates the status of the database record.

However, about 10-20% of records in the database do not reset `next_step_id` as expected (with status correctly <> 'active'). I was unable to reproduce when testing myself.

As long as there are no flaws in the logic itself, is there anyone else that could interfere with the cycle execution? What would be the best way to debug it?

Comment: the best way to debug would be to test it with all possible statuses and see if there is any pattern

Comment: why not set `next_step_id = null` on the `markAs` method?